# Android ListView loaded by JSON not showing

Tags: android, json, listview

i'm building a comments system for a timeline but i have  problem loading the comments from JSON, i've used the same method before for loading the posts on the timeline and is working like a charm. Now is loading but not showing anything.

I have 2 layouts, singleitemview.xml that contains the post itself and a listview named listcoment for loading the comments on it:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
             <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listcoments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
             </LinearLayout>
```

This LinearLayout is inside of other 4 linearlayouts.

And the other layout list_comenarios.xml which have the format of the listview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="3dip" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:minWidth="50dip"
        android:contentDescription="Foto perfil"/>
    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/quienLay"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
         android:background="#ABD2FA" >
   <TextView
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:id="@+id/quien"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/quienLay"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
       >
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comentario"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <View 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="1px"      
     android:background="#eee"/>
     <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#eee">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fecha"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textColor="#999"/>
       </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The weird thing is that is not showing any error on the viewlog from the emulator. This are my classes and adapters for loading the array:

The Adapter:

```
package com.gettford.community;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListComentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListComentAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView quien;
        TextView comentario;
        ImageView imagen;
        TextView fecha;


        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_comentarios, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        imagen = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        quien = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quien);
        comentario = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comentario);
        fecha = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
     // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(SingleItemView.IMAGEN), imagen);
        quien.setText(resultp.get(SingleItemView.QUIEN));
        comentario.setText(resultp.get(SingleItemView.COMENTARIO));
        fecha.setText("Publicado "+resultp.get(SingleItemView.FECHA));
        // Capture ListView item click

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

And the class that loads each post separate:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class SingleItemView extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    // Declare Variables
    String quien;
    String contenido;
    String imagen;
    String idpost;
    String fecha;
    public static String usuarioID;
    public static SessionManager session;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListComentAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    static String IDPOST = "idpost";
    static String QUIEN = "quien";
    static String IMAGEN = "imagen";
    static String COMENTARIO = "comentario";
    static String FECHA = "fecha";
   ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

   static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "APIKEY";
   static private final String VIDEO = "VIDEOTOLOAD";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        session.checkLogin();
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Get the result of rank
        // Get the result of country
        quien = i.getStringExtra("quien");
        // Get the result of population
        contenido = i.getStringExtra("contenido");
        // Get the result of flag
       imagen = i.getStringExtra("imagen");
       fecha = i.getStringExtra("fecha");


       HashMap<String, String> usuario = session.getUserDetails();

       usuarioID = usuario.get(SessionManager.KEY_USER_ID);

       YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView)
               findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
                          youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

        // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
        TextView txtquien = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quien);
        TextView txtcontenido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contenido);
        TextView txtfecha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fecha);

        // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
       ImageView imgflag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);

        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtquien.setText(quien);
        txtcontenido.setText(contenido);
        txtfecha.setText(fecha);

        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
       imageLoader.DisplayImage(imagen, imgflag);
    }


    public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SingleItemView.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Comentarios del post");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://www.server.com/showing/data/json/encoded");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("comentarios");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects

                    map.put("quien", jsonobject.getString("quien"));
                    map.put("imagen", jsonobject.getString("imagen"));
                    map.put("comentario", jsonobject.getString("comentario"));
                    map.put("fecha", jsonobject.getString("fecha"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listcoments);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListComentAdapter(SingleItemView.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Error cargando el servicio de video de YouTube",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
                   @Override
                   public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
            boolean wasRestored) {
                          player.loadVideo(VIDEO);
                   }
}
```

As i said i used the same classes and adapters with different names to load the posts and is working fine.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've checked the logcat and there's no error on nothing showing. So i've changed the name of the array to see if the JSON parser wasn't working and it is, normally, how can i debug this?

Comment: 1. Follow ViewHolder pattern in custom adapter for ListView

Comment: 2. I doubt JSON loading and parsing, so check whether you are getting any exception there.

Comment: Thanks for replying. @PareshMayani I'm pretty new in Android Programming, can you explain me a little better please? Thanks!

Comment: @ShijuB I suppose you mean the Original ListViewAdapter? or what class do you mean?

Comment: First things first. To your `ListComentAdapter.getView()` add a line at the end, that does a `Log.d()`. Just to see how often and with what values (and if at all) it is called. What's in logcat then is what should be in your listview.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal">
         <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listcoments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
         </LinearLayout>
```

....

with

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal">
         <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listcoments"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
         </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself:

The problem wasnt the classes or the adapter, the problem was the XML:

I've changed this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
             <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listcoments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
             </LinearLayout>
```

To this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10.0dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listcoments"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

And everything showed up instantly

I hope this can be useful for someone else.

Regards